# DataTables JQuery giving warning requested unknown parameter for response from a separate independent AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have actually setup a **fnDrawCallback** listener for my datatable whose purpose is to basically setup onClickListener for button that is drawn in the datatable ... The button itself initiates an AJAX request for loading DOM (with a separate url ofc) as shown below in the code

```
$('#dataTable-current').DataTable({
      'processing': true,
      'serverSide': true,
      'destroy':true,
      'serverMethod': 'post',
      'aaSorting':[],
      'ajax': {
          'url':'loadInfo/current_audit.php'
      },
      'fnDrawCallback':function(){
          $(".action-btn").on('click',function(){
            var target_row = $(this).closest("tr"); // this line did the trick
              console.log(target_row)
            var aPos = $("#dataTable-current").dataTable().fnGetPosition(target_row.get(0)); 
            var courseData=$('#dataTable-current').DataTable().row(aPos).data()
            delete courseData.action
            delete courseData.allocate_faculty
            var json_courseData=JSON.stringify(courseData)
            console.log(json_courseData)
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "loadModal/current_audit_modal.php",
                // dataType: "json",
                data: json_courseData,
                success: function(output)
                {
                    // $("#"+x).text("Deleted Successfully");
                    target_row.append(output);
                    $('#update-del-modal').modal('show')
                                    $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#update-del-modal', function () {
                                         $("#update-del-modal").remove(); 
                                     });
                }
            });
          })
      },
      'columns': [
         { data: 'cname' },
         { data: 'cid' },
         { data: 'sem' },
         { data: 'dept_name' },
         { data: 'dept_applicable' },
         { data: 'max' },
         { data: 'min' },
         { data: 'no_of_allocated' },
         { data: 'allocate_faculty' },
         { data: 'action' },
      ],
      'columnDefs': [ {
        'targets': [4,8,9], // column index (start from 0)
        'orderable': false, // set orderable false for selected columns
     }]
   });
```

**Here is the code for loadModal/current_audit_modal.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['email']) && $_SESSION['role']=='inst_coor'){
    include_once('../../config.php');
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true); 
    $cid=mysqli_escape_string($conn,$data['cid']);
    $cname=mysqli_escape_string($conn,$data['cname']);
    $sem=mysqli_escape_string($conn,$data['sem']);
    $max=mysqli_escape_string($conn,$data['max']);
    $min=mysqli_escape_string($conn,$data['min']);
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"select academic_year from current_sem_info WHERE currently_active=1");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $year=$row['academic_year'];
    $dept_div='';
    $checkbox_div='';
    echo '<div class="modal fade mymodal" id="update-del-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle1" aria-hidden="true">
                                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                      <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle1">Action</h5>
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                </button>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="modal-body">
                                        <nav>
                                            <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                                              <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-delete-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-delete" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-delete" aria-selected="true">Deletion</a>
                                              <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-update-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-update" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-update" aria-selected="false">Update</a>
                                              <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-moreinfo-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-moreinfo" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-moreinfo" aria-selected="false">More Info</a>

                                            </div>
                                        </nav>
                                        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                                          <!--Deletion-->
                                           <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-delete" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-delete-tab">
                                           <form class="delete_course_form">
                                           <div class="form-group">
                                             <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1"><b>Are you sure you want to delete?</b>
                                             </label>
                                             <br>
                                             <input type="hidden" name="cid" value="' . $cid . '">
                                             <input type="hidden" name="sem" value="' . $sem . '">
                                             <input type="hidden" name="year" value="' . $year . '">
                                             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete_course_btn" name="delete_course">Yes</button>
                                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" name="no">No</button>
                                           </div>
                                         </form>
                                           </div>
                                          <!--end Deletion-->
                                          <!--Update-->
                                          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-update" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-update-tab">
                                            <form method="POST" action="ic_queries/addcourse_queries.php" class="update_course_form">
                                              <div class="form-row mt-4">
                                                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                      <label for="cname"><b>Name</b></label>
                                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="New Course Name" name="coursename" value="' . $cname . '">

                                                  </div>
                                                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                      <label for="courseid"><b>Course ID</b></label>
                                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="00000" name="courseidnew" value="' . $cid . '">
                                                      <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  placeholder="00000" name="courseidold" value="' . $cid. '">
                                                  </div>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="semester"><b>Semester</b></label> 
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Semester" name="semnew" value="' . $sem . '">
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" placeholder="Semester" name="semold" value="' . $sem . '">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="semester"><b>Year</b></label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled required="required" placeholder="Year" name="year" value="' . $year . '">
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" placeholder="Year" name="year" value="' . $year . '">
                                                </div>        
                                              </div>
                                              <br>
                                              ' . $dept_div . '
                                              <br>
                                              <div class="form-row">
                                                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                      <label for="max"><b>Max</b></label>
                                                      <input type="number" class="form-control" required="required" name="max" placeholder="120" value="' . $max . '">
                                                  </div>
                                                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                      <label for="min"><b>Min</b></label>
                                                      <input type="number" class="form-control" required="required" name="min" placeholder="1" value="' . $min . '">
                                                  </div>
                                              </div>
                                              <label for="branch"><b>Branches to opt for</b></label>
                                              <br>
                                              ' . $checkbox_div . '
                                              <br>
                                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="update_course_btn" name="update_course">Update</button>
                                            </form>
                                            <br>
                                          </div>
                                          <!--end Update-->
                                          <!--MoreInfo-->
                                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-moreinfo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-moreinfo-tab-tab">
                                            <label><b>More Info</b>
                                           </div>
                                          <!--end MoreInfo-->
                                          <div class="modal-footer">
                                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" name="close">Close</button>
                                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="save_changes">Save changes</button>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>';
}
?>
```

**And this is what I get as response from the browser but also a warning message pops up instantly**

[image]

Along with this warning message

[image]

The DOM gets loaded with the response but also with a warning!!!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you sure the error is to do with the button. Try removing all the button code and see if you still get the error. Perhaps the error is to do with loadInfo/current_audit.php. Is allocate_faculty output in that page?

Comment: Okay I tried commenting the ajax part of the button ... but still no help... But when i commented **fnDrawCallback** property I didn't get any warning.... I think there is some problem with **fnDrawCallback**

Comment: @mattbloke Do u think there is an alternative way to set event listener on the button after the dom for it is loaded?

Comment: Can you put some break points before this line  delete courseData.allocate_faculty. I think deleting this property could be causing your problem because its no longer available to be rendered by the datatable.

Comment: You are a genius @mattbloke ... This worked magically ... Thanks a lot

Comment: U can submit ur answer so that I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think deleting courseData.allocate could be causing your problem because its no longer available to be rendered by the datatable. Amend the follow line.

```
delete courseData.allocate_faculty
```

Comment: I deleted courseData.allocate_faculty because it was unnecessary to send to the server..... And I didn't realize this could be the bug ... Thanks once again for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

check your data in database at row 9 column 8, it's usually contain (' "" : etc)

Comment: Actually row 9 column 8 is a button and it is indeed getting loaded .... The warning is caused by fnDrawCallback I suppose because when i comment it it is working absolutely fine